# UISlider error : Property 'value' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderr;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl2;
```

.m file:

```
- (IBAction)slidersact:(id)sender {
    self.lbl2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", sender.value];
                                                      [error with ^^]
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.sliderr.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.sliderr.maximumValue = 100.0f;
    self.lbl2.text = @"0";
}
```

Error:

> Property 'value' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id is any object , you need to identify your object using your control name as like  `- (IBAction)slidersact:(UISlider *)sender` instead of `- (IBAction)slidersact:(id)sender`

```
 - (IBAction)slidersact:(UISlider *)sender {
  self.lbl2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", sender.value];
}
```

Comment: Or change `sender.value` to `[sender value]`.

Comment: (IBAction)slidersact:(UISlider *)sender  its work...thanx lot